# Can I retrieve Firefox localStorage data for a URL that no longer exists?

Tags: firefox, javascript, local-storage

Kind of a weird question, but here's the basic situation.

A while back I wrote a basic little todo app for use by some coworkers on an internal corporate network, and I was hosting it on a shared drive. For the sake of persistence without having to set up a web server, user data was being stored in the browser's localStorage.

Recently, the SysAdmins have been reworking the network drive addressing system, which has resulted in a change to the URL for my little app. Of course, this means that the page no longer has access to the same localStorage obejct, and anyone who has been using my app has now "lost" their data, even though it's still stored somewhere by Firefox. (We're all using **Firefox 31** on **Windows 7**, in case that changes anything.)

So the question is, can I retrieve that localStorage data? My first thought, kludge though it is, was to have a user add an entry to their `hosts` file to point the old URL to another file that will export the data (or, for that matter, point to a trivial file and grab the data manually in the web console). But, as you might have guessed, the `hosts` file is locked down and we don't have admin rights.

As a final note, I am aware of the various Firefox addons that help with localStorage, but as I mentioned before this is all happening on an isolated corporate network, so bringing in an addon for such a trivial reason is a non-starter.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, I found that localStorage data is stored in a sqlite file called `webappsstore.sqlite` in your Firefox profile directory. On Windows, this can be found at `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profile ID}\webappsstore.sqlite`. To read its contents I used a little Python script that uses the `sqlite3` package:

```
import os, sqlite3
profiles = os.path.join(os.environ('APPDATA'),'Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles')
profile = os.path.join(profiles, os.listdir(profiles)[0])
db = os.path.join(profile,'webappsstore.sqlite')
print([entry.encode('utf-8') for entry in sqlite3.connect(db).iterdump()])
```

(I used Python 3, not sure if there are differences in the Python 2 version of sqlite3.)

This will output a lot of data; I recommend redirecting into a file. The data will be in SQL data creation statements. Each entry in local storage has a domain and key associated with it in a table. The URL is always written backwards in the database. You're looking for something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO "webappsstore2" VALUES('moc.elpmaxe.www.:https:443','myLocalStorageKey','{"key":"value","pairs":["go","here"]}')
```

You'll find your localStorage key-value pairs somewhere in the output.

Comment: !rewsna lufesu siht rof sknahT

Comment: You can also download the free DB Browser for SQLite from https://sqlitebrowser.org/ and browse through the `webappsstore2` table.